# $(this).closest('h5').find('.comment').text returns " " (nothing)

Tags: jquery, html

This code works on my other site (and is a mainstream answer):
 `var qtd = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();`

However, I am doing something similar which keeps returning a blank or undefined:

`$(this).closest('.comment').find('h5').text(); //returns ""
$(this).closest('h5').find('.comment').text(); // returns ""
$(this).closest('h5').find('.comment').val(); //returns undefined`

I also tried a 'p' tag instead thinking it could  be a "CSS" issue:

```
info= $(this).closest('p').find('.comment').text(); //returns ""
```

EDIT: Here is my server side PHP code, it very well could be a PHP issue (as no one is responding I am assuming my jQuery is correct):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) { ?>

<h5 class="comment bold"> <?php echo $row['comment']; ?> </h5></div>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

**Full JS/AJAX Code (as requested). This could give a better understanding of what I am doing.**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.update-btn').click(function() {
  var edit_id= $(this).data("id");
  //var qtd = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val(); //works
 //  var new_info= $(this).closest('.comment').find('h5').text(); // returns ""
  var new_info= $(this).closest('p').find('.comment').text(); // returns ""
// var new_info= $(this).closest('h5').find('.comment').val(); //returns undefined

 alert(new_info);
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'update.php',
  data:{ 
new_info, new_info,
edit_id, edit_id,
  },
  success: function(data){
          alert(data); 
              if(data==1) {
                  alert("Updated");
                  // $('#comments-all').load("#comments-all");
              }if(data=='0'){
                  alert('wrong');
          }    
          } //end success
  }); //end ajax
 }); 
        }); //end doc
```

Comment: What does `this` refer to? We need more of your code to be able to help.

Comment: Show the structure of your HTML, and show where you're using this code.

Comment: The issue is surely related to the context of the javascript function. I'm sure is a `this` related issue. Hard to tell without the code context.

Comment: this is referring to a click. I will add in my whole code. My HTML is coming from a PHP loop which could be the issue.